# Cómo añadir una clase a un html que crea Woocommerce en php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Espero que podáis ayudarme, llevo días intentando hacer esto y ya me vuelvo loco.

Cuando un producto se queda sin stock en Woocommerce el plugin pone Agotado en la página del producto ( en el archive también, pero sólo me interesa como single product) con este html:

`<p class="stock out-of-stock">Out of stock</p>`

¿Cómo puedo meter una clase nueva en esa línea de html?
¿No consigo encontrar el archivo exacto y la línea exacta que tengo que modificar en el plugin?

Comment: podrias usar esto: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-out-of-stock-message/

Comment: No puedo usar plugin Diego, necesito añadir por código una nueva clase a esa línea de html para poder manejarlo luego por CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Usando JQuery o Javascript puedes agregarle las clases a los elementos que necesites, no importa si haces referencia a una clase ya existente

Javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById("out-of-stock");
element.classList.add("ClaseNueva");
```

JQuery

```
$('.out-of-stock').addClass('ClaseNueva')
```

Comment: Hola TheVicShow. ¿Cómo puedo meter ese Javascript en el Wordpress?

Comment: Te anexo este articulo https://www.emenia.es/javascript-en-wordpress-de-forma-correcta/ para que agregues el codigo Javascript a tu pagina